# unable to use logout function of Tank_auth in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have searched thoroughly for this question but didn't get solution , finally i am posting this question. login, registering new user, is working fine in Tank_auth but logout function seems not working properly for me.it shows following error

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: session_id
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 272

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: ip_address
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 272

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: user_agent
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 272

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: last_activity
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 272

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: session_id
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 288

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: last_activity
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 289

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\system\core\Exceptions.php:185)
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 675

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\system\core\Exceptions.php:185)
Filename: helpers/url_helper.php
Line Number: 542
```

some one told me to modify logout function in auth controller function logout()

```
{
    $this->tank_auth->logout();
    $this->session->sess_create();//modified.....
    $this->_show_message($this->lang->line('auth_message_logged_out'));
    //redirect('','refresh');
}
```

it worked fine but when i refresh the page it redirected me the back to the previous page where the user had loged out, and then i searched again  and got this line to be modified form set to unset_userdata..... in tank_auth class.

```
this->ci->session->unset_userdata(array('user_id' => '', 'username' => '', 'status' => ''));
```

this is what i did so far eagrly waiting for help..

Comment: @StuartM beat me to the edit

Comment: @stuartM do i need to add anything more to make my question clear?